# • Field: android - should NOT have additional property 'androidServicesFile'

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Im trying to use the FCM for Push Notification using Expo API.
I have follow this documnetation to make it work: https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/

When I try to create an APK(to test the FCM if it works) using this command: `expo build:android` it shows me this error:

```
Error: Problem validating fields in app.json. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/configuration/
 • Field: android - should NOT have additional property 'androidServicesFile'.
Couldn't publish because errors were found. (See logs above.) Please fix the errors and try again.
```

This is the app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "TestApp",
    "slug": "testApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/logo.png",
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
    "android": {
      "package": "test.app",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
      "androidServicesFile":"./google-services.json", //this is what I have added
        
      },
    },

    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

The google service json is generated on the firebase when I have created an application for andorid, which has the api key.